# How to compare with two strings if one is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to compare two strings, one is all characters and the other is has a few of them hidden. I need to mark the difference using CSS

example:
Astring: `123哈哈哈321哈哈哈123哈哈哈`
Bstring: `123***321***123***`

result: '123**哈哈哈**321**哈哈哈**123**哈哈哈**'

I trying to use split with `Astring` and `Bstring`, and use `forEach` compare the difference with the index, when I get the index, I can use `forEach`, run `Astring.split('')`, and `Astring.split('')` compare with index, this index use CSS

```js
let resultDom = document.querySelector('.resultDom')
let aStringWithSplit = [1, 2, 3, '哈', '哈', '哈', 3, 2, 1, '哈', '哈', '哈', 1, 2, 3, '哈', '哈', '哈']
let bStringWithSplit = [1, 2, 3, '*', '*', '*', 3, 2, 1, '*', '*', '*', 1, 2, 3, '*', '*', '*']
let getIndexWithHidden = []
let result = ''
bStringWithSplit.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item === '*') {
    getIndexWithHidden.push(index)
  }
})
aStringWithSplit.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (getIndexWithHidden.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
    result += `<span style='color: red;'>${item}</span>`
  } else {
    result += `<span>${item}</span>`
  }
})
resultDom.innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div class='resultDom'></div>
```

but this result have to many `<span>`, if this string too long,
how can I improve this code?

Comment: Loop over both with a for loop, and compare the values for each index. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the number of `<span>`s, you can group adjacent similar values and add them all to a single `<span>`, here is an example:

```js
const a = '123哈哈哈321哈哈哈123哈哈哈';
const b = '123***321***123***';

const result = b.split(/(\*+)/).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const group = a.substring(acc.prevIndex, acc.prevIndex + curr.length);
  if (curr.includes('*')) {
    acc.result += `<span style="color: red">${group}</span>`
  } else {
    acc.result += group;
  }
  acc.prevIndex += curr.length
  return acc;
}, { prevIndex: 0, result: '' }).result;

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="output"><div>
```

Here, I've used `b.split(/(\*+)/)` to split the mask string into groups of adjacent `*` and groups of adjacent other characters.

Then, I'm reducing the array of groups and, I'm using `a.substring(acc.prevIndex, acc.prevIndex + curr.length)` (where `acc.prevIndex` is the number of characters that have been processed so far and `curr.length` is the length of the current group) to get the characters from the string that needs to be processed and then, add them to a `<span>` if the group is all `*` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split anything because strings can already be indexed like arrays, and you only need to run the loop once because you know the strings will be the same length. This will make your code a bit faster

Also, as [Rene van der Lende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015909/rene-van-der-lende) pointed out in a comment, you only need to add a `<span>` tag if the text is colored.

```js
let a = '123哈哈哈321哈哈哈123哈哈哈';
let b = '123***321***123***';

let result = '';
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  const item = a[i];
  result += item !== b[i] ? `<span style='color: red;'>${item}</span>` : `${item}`;
}

document.querySelector('.resultDom').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div class='resultDom'></div>
```

I also used the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of an if-else statement to make the code a bit shorter. This isn't required, but it looks nicer.

Comment: OP asked for saving on number of `<span>`. The 'else' operator does not necessarily require 'spanning'.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thanks for the great catch! I've updated my answer and code to do this (with attribution, of course).